How to replicate tinymce V6 html sanitisation on Django templates?
So I'm using both tinymce and React-hook-forms to create a form which is linked to a Django backend. I've recently updated tinymce to version 6 but I have noticed that now it automatically sanitises/minifies the default values upon mounting
I.e. if the default value is:
<p>Random text<p>

<p>Random text 2<p>

Then the final tinymce result will be:
<p>Random text<p>
<p>Random text 2<p>

I need to replicate this logic on the Django template backend otherwise the default template value and the actual tinymce value will be different and set dirty fields equal to true on react-hook-forms. This is easy to do for small templates, I've created my own personal python sanitisation function but this does not work for large templates.
Is there any way for me to replicate the tinymce sanitisation process on the backend or somehow turn it off in the tinymce config frontend?
Note: I have already tried a couple of backend sanitisation libraries like django-htmlmin but this hasn't worked.
